# A DataTable named 'Table' already belongs to this DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net

when i am adding second table(dtResult) to data set that time it's giving error

A DataTable named 'Table' already belongs to this DataSet.

```
DataTable dtSession = new DataTable();
DataTable dtResult= new DataTable();
dtResult.TableName = "A";
dtSession.TableName = "B";
dtSession = objOpt.GetSearchDetails().Copy();
ds.Tables.Add(dtSession);
dtResult = objOpt.Search_Synchronous().Copy();
ds.Tables.Add(dtResult);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to name the tables after getting the copy from your method and before adding it to the `DataSet`.

```
DataTable dtResult= new DataTable();

dtSession = objOpt.GetSearchDetails().Copy();
dtSession.TableName = "B";
ds.Tables.Add(dtSession);


dtResult = objOpt.Search_Synchronous().Copy();
dtResult.TableName = "A";
ds.Tables.Add(dtResult);
```

Since you are getting the copy from your methods `objOpt.GetSearchDetails().Copy()` and `objOpt.Search_Synchronous().Copy()`, they are overwriting the names assigned to the table previously, and both of these are returning the table with name `Table`, that is why you are getting this error

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this exception today, but it had nothing to do with adding a DataTable.

I have an ASP.Net Core WebApi, and in the Post and Put endpoints, I was attempting to save/update the new record *and also* search in the database (in the same table) for an existing record with the same details, and if such a record exists, to update it.

I was getting that exception when it tried to save these changes.

The solution was to split it up, save the new/updated record first...

```
//  Avoid an "A DataTable named 'Users' already belongs to this DataSet." exception
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

... and then check for an existing record, update it if necessary, and then doing a separate save...

```
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Yup, it's weird, but saving twice fixed this issue for me.

(I appreciate that this doesn't answer this exact StackOverflow question, but for anyone stumbling onto this page when they hit this strangely-worded exception, this'll be a lifesaver !)

Answer (score 0):

I received this error when running command.ExecuteDataSet on a stored procedure where I declared a table variable then queried that table multiple times to return several datatables in the dataset. Because each datatable was queried from the same table, they all had the same name '@t'.  I was able to resolve it by creating multiple table variables with different names in the stored procedure.